# How slower is ToStringBuilder, HashCodeBuilder, EqualsBuilder using reflection

Tags: java, apache-commons, stringbuilder

`ToStringBuilder` provides a convenient way to implement the `toString` method, just like this

```
  @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this, ToStringStyle.SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE); 
    }
```

And almost the same thing to implement `hashCode` and equals method.

But in the documentation and in some answers of stackoverflow it says that it's a little slower.

I rarely use the method equals or hashCode in my production code and I only use `toString` in debugging process but not in production, so my question is:
If I implement my bean methods using **EqualsBuilder**, **HashCodeBuilder**, **ToStringBuilder** with reflection and I rarely use `toString`, `hashCode` or `equals` is it still performance penalty?

Comment: There's only one way to find out: Profiling... (But I can tell you the answer right away: You won't notice any difference)

Comment: If you rarely call the method, it can't be a performance penalty... Note that the fact that you don't call it directly does not mean it is not called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how to use it. Eg if you use HashCodeBuilder like this

```
public int hashCode() {
    HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this);
}
```

it's clear even without measuring that it will be expensive since it's based on reflection. But this way is not so expensive

```
public int hashCode() {
   HashCodeBuilder hb = new HashCodeBuilder();
   hb.append(field1);
   hb.append(field2);
   ...
   return hb.toHashCode();
}
```

the only problem is that it creates an extra object which can be avoided if to do the same manually.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to performance impacts it is always better to measure yourself. Nobody can tell you how it will affect your system. Are you sure you rarely use equals and hashCode? They are also used for example by Map and Set, which are pretty common constructs.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use "Caliper" to do the microbenchmark test.  However, with the exception of ToStringBuilder, I won't use the `EqualsBuilder` and `HashCodeBuilder` instead I would use the one generated by the IDE.

The reason being Equals and HashCode tend to be used regularly throughout the application and the IDEs generate a good enough implementation.

On the other hand, I use `ToStringBuilder` because I generally use toString for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

If your class is immutable, or the fields that are used for hashCode and toString do not change, you can cache the results of hashCode and toString.  So that the slow reflective code is only called once.  This gives you most of the speed gains of writing custom code for hashCode and toString, yet is (usually) much easier to code.

This trick is used in [String.hashCode()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.hashCode%28%29).

```
int hashCode = 0;
String toString = null;

public int hashCode() {
  int h = hashCode;  // local copy for thread safety, see String
  if (h == 0) {
     h = HashCodeBuilder.workYourMagic();
     hashCode = h;
  }
  return h;
}

public String toString() {
  String s = toString;
  if (s == null) {
    s = ToStringBuilder.workYourMagic();
    toString = s;
  }
  return s;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this relates to OP's question. He's asking whether it's worth doing one optimisation, not what other optimisations he can do.

Comment: This is (usually) easier to do that a full optimization, yet provides most of the speed gains.  I just added a comment to the answer in response to your question.

Comment: I don't really agree that this is easier than writing `return HashCodeBuilder.append(a).append(b).build();`, nor that it provides the same speed advantages. I guess it all depends on your use case; for a sufficiently complex class I could see your point.